# How to use repeated measure anova (within participants) if participants fill in likert scale daily for 10 days?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

With the sample of people participating everyday in a diary study for 10 days. They fill in the same likert scale every day. How then I can use repeated measure anova after finishing the study?

Comment: I would not use RM ANOVA.  I would use a multilevel model. They make fewer assumptions.  Are you set on RM ANOVA for some reason?

Comment: What are you going to predict and with what? But I'd also use a multilevel model rather than RM-ANOVA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.